# Implicit conversion with class templates

Tags: c++

Using the next definitions

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

void f(A* a) {}
```

calling `f(new B)` is possible because `B*` is implicitly converted to `A*`, right?

However, when doing the same with class templates like `std::vector` this generates a compile error.

```
void f(std::vector<A*> v)
{}

int main()
{
    std::vector<B*> v;
    f(v); //error! "no suitable user-defined conversion..."

    return 0;
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::vector<B*>` and `std::vector<A*>` are a completely different types, but `B` is derived from `A`. To copy data from `std::vector<B*>` to `std::vector<A*>` use `std::copy` and `std::back_inserter`:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::copy
#include <iterator>  // std::back_inserter

std::vector<B*> b;
std::vector<A*> a;
std::copy( b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter( a ) );
```

... or initialize `a` with uniform initialization:

```
std::vector<B*> b;
std::vector<A*> a{ b.begin(), b.end() };
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<B*>` and `std::vector<A*>` are different at all, since their template arguments' type are different.

As a workaround, you can use another ctor of [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), i.e. `template<class InputIt> std::vector::vector(InputIt first, InputIt last)`, such as:

```
f(std::vector<A*>(v.begin(), v.end()));
```

or just(need c++11)

```
f({v.begin(), v.end()});
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/YXXX26730)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comment, `std::vector<A*>` is a different type than `std::vector<B*>`. That doesn't prevent you from storing `B*` objects in the `std::vector<A*>` vector. As you surmised, base class pointers can point to derived objects, which is why you can store them in the base class vector.

You also should make `v` a reference in `f`'s prototype.

Punchline: You don't really need `std::vector<B*>`.